# error when running ng build --prod from command line for visual studio angular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

I created a .net core angular project from visual studio and was able to build it successfully from visual studio but when I run the same step from command line

**D:\tempvsts\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\ClientApp>ng build --prod**

error

> You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build
>   command.

the same when I publish from visual studio I can see in the output that ngbuild --prod work. 
So why does it not work from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Error says, you need to execute the ng build command in the root folder of your project, it will contain angular.json are you running there?

Answer (score 0):

You should be inside the project folder where the angular.json file is located. Can you tell us the folder location you are running this command in?

Comment: it should be a comment rather than an answer